# Why do I get an error in this code when using "using namespace std;" and "bits/stdc++.h"?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, ambiguous, name-lookup

Actually this code works fine in "DEV C++", but when I put it into my "Hacker-Rank" panel it gives this error "reference to function is ambiguous", although all the online compilers are giving errors...

I don't think here function overloading is somewhere interrupting, because this error mostly comes in function overloading.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int function(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    

    if(n<=0){
        return(0);
    }
    else{
        function(n);
    }

}
int function(int n)
{
    if (n<=9)
    {
        cout<<"experiment";
    }
    
    else{
        cout<<"Greater than 9";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[The error with clang is](https://godbolt.org/z/W69n7x):

```
<source>:20:9: error: reference to 'function' is ambiguous
        function(n);
        ^
<source>:8:5: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'function'
int function(int n);
    ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.0.0/../../../../include/c++/11.0.0/bits/std_function.h:111:11: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::function'
    class function;
          ^
// ... and more ....
```

Comment: Please double and triple check that even for hackerrank participation that antipattern has actually a benefit for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Don't `using namespace std;`

Comment: If you have already included `<bits/stdc++.h>` then why include other header ?

Comment: please do not paraphrase the error message. Include it verbatim in the question. The message has useful information that you should not ignore

Comment: I made the title more descriptive. Admittedly it kind of forshadows the two currently existing answers (one of them being mine). I am convinced that the value of this Q/As is improved by this new title. But I will accept if anybody undoes my title change.

Comment: @Yunnosch imho its a bit too generic and not quite reflecting OPs intent. Should be more like "Why is ... and .. causing trouble in *this code*?", answer can then still explain the general case. I'll try to rephrase it

Comment: @Yunnosch i also added the error message, not sure how this interferes with "although all the online compilers are giving errors..." which is a typo I suppose ("are *not* giving errors" ?!?)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think the same. The post would make more sense with that "not". fly_high, please clarify.

Comment: @Yunnosch not sure if the complete error message is too much of a spoiler and corrupting your answers. Please review and I'd be fine with removing the last part of the message

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am not afraid. My answer rests on being tested.  OPs code gets the error, Vlads Code fixes it. My code fixes it. I also like you title, it is less daring (and blessed by "not me" having edited it...), but it still can provides the value I aimed for.

Comment: @Yunnosch great. Good luck with finding the duplicates ;) Cheers

Comment: Well.... I don't think that anybody using those antipatterns actually reflects to the point to question it. So no question author is likely to accept the dupe. Only if I lose contenance I might succumb to the temptation of actually duping something pointing here. I should not.... But I am human.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters this else code block

```
else{
    function(n);
}
```

returns nothing.

Though it is allowed but confuses readers of the program because they expect that if there is an explicit return statement in the if sub-statement then a similar return statement should be in the else sub-statement.

It seems the name `function` declared in the global name space conflicts with the standard name `std::function` due to the using directive.

```
using namespace std;
```

Write

```
else{
    return ::function(n);
}
```

Comment: Great example of that antipattern making trouble. I am tempted to dupe-close-vote many questions referring here....

Comment: you explained it in a bit of lines awesome i was having this error in many codes but now i just change the name of fuction and...yey it works fine for every situation....thanks...

Comment: @fly_high In any case it is better to use qualified names.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` combined with the directive `using namespace std`.

`<bits/stdc++.h>` includes most (all, depending on the age of the version you have with your compiler) headers related to the C++ standard library.

One of the headers included by `<bits/stdc++.h>` (since C++11) is `<functional>`, which declares a templated class `std::function`.  `std::function` has a templated constructor that can accept a single argument of any type.

In your `main()`, anything declared (visible to the compiler) named `function` is a candidate for being used by the statement `function(n)`.   The directive `using namespace std` tells the compiler to consider names within `std`  as candidates.   According to rules of the language, both your declared `function()` and `std::function` are equally good matches for the name `function`.

The real fix has two parts.   The first is to avoid using headers like `<bits/stdc++.h>` and, instead, only include standard headers that are *actually* needed by your program.

The second part is to avoid using the directive `using namespace std` excessively, or even at all.   It can cause names (of types, functions, variables, etc) within standard headers to accidentally match names in your code.

If you do a search, you will find plenty of explanations of why to avoid both `<bits/stdc++.h>` and to avoid `using namespace std` (or other `using` directives).   Both have their uses, but both introduce hard-to-avoid gotchas (such as you have experienced).

Answer (score 1):

Vlad has shown that working around the problems caused by `using namespace std;` can solve your problem. That is a good answer.

Funnily, you can also fix your problem by not applying the antipattern `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Even without Vlads proposed improvement.

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int function(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    

    if(n<=0){
        return(0);
    }
    else{
        function(n);
    }

}
int function(int n)
{
    if (n<=9)
    {
        cout<<"experiment";
    }
    
    else{
        cout<<"Greater than 9";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More info on why I dare to describe that as "antipattern" is here:
[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)